# WP8 - How to create a button with action when dragging

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, effect

How can I create the same effect when the camera button 6tag, ie change the button using the same finger and dragging the image below. Also equal to the pro camera application button that switches between photo and video.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not a simple task. You can do it using Triggers inside button content.

Comment: Could not show me any example for me to understand? Thank you.